Do any technical details of Amdahl's Aspen survive?
Aspen was Amdahl's project to build their own clone of IBM's MVS mainframe operating system.
Amdahl cancelled the project at some point in the 1980s (1987?). It was never formally released, but (apparently) some customers ran beta copies. There is very little information about it available online though.
One of the few sources of information I can find is this document from Stanford University Library, which indicates that the Library holds extensive archives on a 1980s era project by the defunct Research Libraries Group to build a library management system running under Amdahl's operating system. However, none of those documents appear to have been put online. It appears most of them are rather high level (e.g. project status reports), but there are some tantalising hints at technical details among them (for example, page 165 mentions "lengths & displacements for Aspen version of SPIRES").
Fritz Trapnell's oral history at the Computer History Museum has some very high-level details about both Aspen and its demise (see page 30):

...Gene [Amdahl] was also a factor in something we attempted to do in software, which was to create an operating system that was an alternative to MVS. In the last days before he left, he was enthusiastic about embarking on this venture, and that enthusiasm kicked off the project and sustained it for some time after he left. It was called Aspen. We put together a small group to design and implement it. We thought a lot more interesting and flexible than MVS, and it had an MVS emulation capability – you could run MVS programs under it. But it really foundered because IBM violently objected to the MVS facility in Aspen, didn't believe it wasn't stolen, which it wasn't. It was designed and written by one of our people who had never even worked for IBM.
But IBM had had trouble with code that was stolen. I don't have any firsthand evidence, but we heard rumors that Fujitsu got in a lot of difficulty with IBM...
Anyway, IBM threatened Amdahl with legal proceedings, so we dropped that project. I'm not so sure that developing Aspen was as wise an idea as we originally thought. But Gene Amdahl was very keen about it. And maybe if he'd stayed he would have guided it through, but I don't know. We had a very difficult time with it. For Amdahl, it was expensive; whereas UTS paid for itself.

Anyone aware of anything else? Does anyone know who any of the beta sites were, other than RLG?

Fujitsu (and Hitachi) did get in a "lot of difficulty with IBM" owing to piracy of IBM MVS but it appears Amdahl was not involved.

@JohnDallman Amdahl and Fujitsu collaborated closely - in fact, Fujitsu partially owned Amdahl - which potentially left Amdahl legally exposed, even though they always insisted they were ignorant of Fujitsu’s theft. I don’t know this for a fact, but I speculate that may have played some role in killing Aspen - IBM may have said “we promise won’t sue you over your collaboration with Fujitsu if you agree to kill Aspen off”
